# Startup disk space mysteriously being consumed

Tags: hard-drive, startup, disk-space

Lately, my Mac OS X Yosemite has been having this weird issue where my startup disk keeps getting consumed by an unknown source.

Every time I restart my computer, the disk space would come back (let's say 3 GBs), only to be mysteriously eaten again until I have little to 0 disk space again (<200 MB).

What I've tried:

1. Using DiskSpaceX to check out what's eating my disk space and deleting the unnecessary files/folder
2. Buying CleanMyMac3 and cleaning the space. I would reclaim some space, but only to be mysteriously eaten again after an hour or two.

I'm at my wit's end in this issue, and am interested in maybe some software, culprit, or explanation that would show me what's continually eating my disk space.

Comment: Did you try disabling local time machine backups?

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard disabling what?

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Time Machine isn't on unfortunately

Comment: BTW, 3GB of space on a drive is already *critical*. 10% free ought to be considered absolute minimum, better 15%.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know :(

Comment: Then it's time to get to work, laying that off to somewhere else. The rest would not then be such an issue anyway.

Comment: Do you know if something's using massive amounts of RAM? The page file might be growing and filling the space, although you'd start seeing major problems if that were the case... Just a thought.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard This is what my Activity Monitor shows: http://puu.sh/mDbmS/5f451662ed.png

Comment: @theGreenCabbage looks normal to me. I'll give it some thought and get back to you if I think of something.

Comment: Have you tried to use [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) to find out what is taking space?

Comment: @Mattia Does Disk Inventory X + MacCleaner3 count? I just want to see in real time what's taking up space, kind of like a real-time Activity Monitor. EDIT: My bad - it looks like Daisy Disk allows this

Comment: @theGreenCabbage hope you can identify and solve the your problem.

Comment: @Mattia just to be clear - it does do real-time right? I'm looking at it and it doesn't seem like to be changing anything.

Comment: It doesn't update the information in real time. But if you take a look at the daisy before and after you should localise the different of space. I don't know if this is what you need!! But I used it a lot of time to find out unnecessary files and backup.